# How to set teleriks WPF IsTouchEnabled property on application level?

Tags: wpf, telerik

In http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/touch-support it states that it is possible to set the `IsTouchEnabled` to false on application level, but where/how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example in your `App.xaml.cs` file:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        Telerik.Windows.Input.Touch.TouchManager.IsTouchEnabled = false;
    }
}
```